# Delete item from ItemControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My class is has a ObservableCollection of my viewmodel class and I set the itemsource of the Itemcontrol in xaml as below

```
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ConditionItems}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Expander Background="#FFD0D7EB">
                        <StackPanel>
                                <Button Content="Delete" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="180" Margin="0,0,12,10" Command="{Binding DeleteItem}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                                </Button>                             </StackPanel>
                    </Expander>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
```

For some reason my DeleteItem is never called.

```
    private RelayCommand _DeleteRule;
    private void DoDeleteRule(object item)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("in del");
        }
    }

    public ICommand DeleteItem
    {
        get
        {
            if (_DeleteRule == null)
                _DeleteRule = new RelayCommand(o => DoDeleteRule(o));
            return _DeleteRule;
        }
    }
```

Am I doing anything wrong in xaml?

Comment: Where is `DeleteItem` defined? Is it part of parent view model or item view model?

Comment: @dkozl I have tried placing it in viewmodel (The problem there is that my ObservableCollection is list of viewmodel so even if the function is called, I can't place it there). I have tried placing it in xaml.cs file which has my ObservableCollection list. In both cases it does not work

Answer (score 5):

The `ItemsControl` is bound using `{Binding ConditionItems}`, so it expects the `DeleteItem` command to be inside the subitems of that list. I guess this is not the case, the `DeleteItem` exists on the `ViewModel`.

You could bind to the `DataContext` of the `Window` for example, where you can find the `DeleteItem` command. Or create a proxy element.

Comment: If I place Delete button outside the ItemControl, then how would the user know which item he is deleting?

Comment: Not. That's why I didn't propose to move it.

Answer (score 3):

I found it. My xaml should be

```
<Button Content="Delete" Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteItem,
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                          AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                                </Button>
```

Comment: That was indeed what I meant. Didn't have the editor to write the code though.